# Why does the meta viewport not work for android (cordova 5.1.1)?

Tags: html, css, angularjs, cordova

After updating my app to cordova 5.1.1, the meta viewport doesn't work anymore on android. The app is not showen correctly. I have tested a lot of solutions but I still have this problem. How can I enable the viewport (for android) in order to make my app responsive through the meta viewport? 
Thanks!

Comment: Could you give your current viewport settings?

Comment: This is my actual meta:  <meta id='metaToChange' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1' name='viewport'/>

Comment: This one works for me:

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />

Documentation can be found here:
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp

Answer (score -1):

This one works for me:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

Documentation can be found here:
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp

Comment: Thank you I have already test it but it has no effect! It seems that the problem is due to the vesrion of cordova. I don't know how to solve this problem.

Comment: are you sure it is Cordova and not the version of Android? Android changed from Webkit to Chromium about a year ago. Could that explain your differences? If not, upgrade your Cordova. 6 is there already. Use the command line to upgrade: 


sudo npm update -g cordova

Comment: And if you wish a specific version of Cordova (the one that worked for you) use: sudo npm install -g cordova@3.1.0-0.2.0 for example

Comment: Possibly relevant: I just identified an issue on Android 5.1.1 where having "minimum-scale=1" in that line made controls like select and button appear as black rectangles, but keeping it out (as in this answer) lets them appear normally.